# How to make Reviewboard site work

Tags: apache, ubuntu-11.04, review-board

I installed review board on my system with all its dependencies. Now i need to set up a reviewboard site. I followed the instructions on the official website on setting up a site; but it did not work. Googled all day for 2 days with no help. The instructions are 98% same everywhere but doesnt work as it says on my system. The problem is - after setup on my localhost every site opens the reviewboard page, including this, except localhost itself.
However the reviewboard page always reads

> "ReviewBoard is taking a nap"
>   I googled errors in apache error.log but didn't find anything helpful. Any help on what i m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, and in your reviewboard settings file (settings.py), turn DEBUG to True.  This gives you a log more information on what is not working.

Either that or run the url where you are receiving the error and from the command line, type:  tail -f /path/to/errorlog

this gives you the debug info.

And then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is usually that there is something mis-configured or a package missing. I have had the same type of issue and the first step is to make sure that the python tools are working correctly.

If you see `ImportError` while trying to use pythonn or pip. The `setuptools` package may have been deleted or the link removed in the Python environment.

To fix the issue, run the setup script for setuptools:

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
```

In Debian or Ubuntu use

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | sudo python
```